# Selecting Slicers in VBA listed as Array since its become a Data Model?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, powerpivot

I cannot select these powerpivot slicers with variables. They are dates (Monday-Saturday or 1/19-1/25). For some reason I cannot figure out how to select the slicers without the static dates and instead my date strings from a Monday string and Saturday string? I tried concatenating them in but no success.

```
Sheets("Phone Report").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Weeks_Ago").VisibleSlicerItemsList =   Array _
    ( _
    "[Phone Cube Query].[Weeks Ago].&[01/12 - 01/17]")   'So want to replace the 01/12 and the 01/17 with my string variables?
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Day_and_Rank").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
    Array( _
    "[Phone Cube Query].[Day and Rank].&[1. Monday]", _
    "[Phone Cube Query].[Day and Rank].&[2. Tuesday]")

Variables:
Today = Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
        If Today = 2 Then
            Todayy = Date 
            Monday = Date - 1
        ElseIf Today = 3 Then
            Todayy = Date 
            Monday = Date - 2
        ElseIf Today = 4 Then
            Todayy = Date
            Monday = Date - 3
        ElseIf Today = 5 Then
            Todayy = Date
            Monday = Date - 4
        ElseIf Today = 1 Then
            Todayy = Date - 2
            Monday = Date - 7
        End If

Todayy=left(Todayy, 5)
Monday=left(Monday, 5)
```

Thanks for any possible help or suggestions.

Comment: I did not know that you could even use VBA with powerPivot, at least in Excel 2010.  What version of Excel are you in?

Comment: What **exactly** is in your variables?

Comment: I'm confused - how would that work if the items are dates in mm/yy format but you have "Sunday" and "Monday"?

Comment: 1/17/15 is actually a saturday.  Why are you doing all of this calculation when you could just do something like weekdayname(weekday(#1/12#))

Comment: The report slicers change every day, so today (Tuesday) it would say 01/19 - 01/20, and I need to select that. Tomorrow though (Wednesday) the slicer will say 01/19 - 01/21, then Thursday 01/19 - 01/22 and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you found an answer by now. I had this issue for weeks and I tried to make complicated loops, but I found an easier way.

Yes, the macro recording shows an array of the slicer information. I found out if you delete the `array()` portion of the code you can do exactly what you need.

Here's my quick example. `Operation` is the variable:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Oper").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array( _"[Actuals_Table].[Oper].& [" & Operation & "]")
```

Changed to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Oper").VisibleSlicerItemsList = "[Actuals_Table].[Oper].&[" & Operation & "]"
```